# How to get velocity and vector of movable body in AndEngine?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-engine

I have a little problem. I am trying to make air hockey android game (something like glow hockey). And durning my adventure with first steps of getting know AndEngine, I've found a following problem:
In air hockey as you may know, player's disc can be moveable by touching it.
 Problem is, that I need to get velocity and vector of player's moves. Why? I want to make perfect physics when player's body collides with hockey's disc(jumps to vector with proper player's velocity). I mean when player moves slowly- hockey's disk, after collision with bodies, will obtain low velocity but vector won't change. etc. Maybe you can tell me better solution of my problem? Are there any AndEngine solutions for this?
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of solving this. First would be through the AndEngine Box2D extension. You could apply circular "bodies" to the pucks and the disk, and play around with physics elements like the mass and friction till you are happy with your result. 
Forum: http://www.andengine.org/forums/physics-box2d-extension/

The other option is to do it manually, which I would only do so if you want a challenge. Personally I would avoid this as there is a lot of maths involved which Box2D will do for you :)